If $a = \lim_{h \mathop \to 0} (1+h)^{1/h}$ then $\lim_{h\mathop\to0} (a^h - 1)/h=1$.
I am teaching differentiation from first principles to high school students. One of the examples I go through is $f(x) = a^x$, from which arises the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{h\mathop\to0} (a^h - 1)/h$.
I point out that $e$ is the number such that if $a=e$ then the above limit is equal to $1$.
This would be easy to prove if I assume the power series expansion for $e^h$, but I would prefer not to do this because the derivation of the power series relies on knowledge of the derivatives of $e^h$, which is what I am trying to prove.
Instead, I am using the limit definition of $e$, namely $\displaystyle\lim_{n \mathop \to \infty} \left(1 + 1/n\right)^n$, or equivalently, $\displaystyle \lim_{h \mathop \to 0} (1+h)^{1/h}$.
I am having some difficulty rearranging $\displaystyle a = \lim_{h \mathop \to 0} (1+h)^{1/h}$ into $\displaystyle\lim_{h\mathop\to0} (a^h - 1)/h=1$. If one removes the limit operator and rearranges the equation, it will of course work, but I am not sure how to do this whilst respecting the rules for limits. I have tried just substituting the first limit into the second, but I cannot assume that both $h$'s tend to $0$ at the same rate.
I would be grateful for any hints or guidance.

In my calculus class I always begin by differentiating the logarithm function (which can be done using the limit $e=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}$), and then the derivative of exponential is obtained as the derivative of an inverse function. I believe there might be direct computations as well, but that looks more complicated.

$((1+h)^\frac1h)^h -1 =h$

@CyclotomicField The two h's are distinct and cannot be assumed to approach zero at the same rate. I addressed this in my question.

Using "$a$" instead of the common sense "$e$" does not make any difference so I will still use $e$.
It takes three steps to achieve the goal (it's a sketch of the proof, you need to fill out details):

Show that the condition is equivalent to $e = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ and the goal is equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty}n(e^{1/n} - 1) = 1$, where $n$ takes value on positive integers.  This can be done by calling $\varepsilon$-$N$ and $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ languages.

Show the sequence $\{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\}$ is strictly increasing (hint: using AM-GM inequality), it then follows by the provided condition that
\begin{align*}
e > \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n, \quad \forall n. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}

Similarly, show  the sequence $\{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n + 1}\}$ is strictly decreasing, and also has limit $e$ by the condition (and $\lim_n a_nb_n = ab$ if $\lim_n a_n = a$ and $\lim_n b_n = b$), whence
\begin{align*}
e < \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n + 1}, \quad \forall n. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}


$\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$ together give a lower bound and an upper bound of the sequence $\{n(e^{1/n} - 1)\}$, which both converge to $1$, you can then finish the proof by the squeeze principle.

The proof of the limit of the upper bound $n\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{n + 1}{n}} -1\right]$ is at most $1$ is slightly more involved.  In case you had difficulty, check the spoiler below.

\begin{align*}& n\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{n + 1}{n}} -1\right]\\= & n\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} -1\right]\\\leq & n\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{(n - 1) + 1 + \frac{1}{n}}{n}- 1\right] \\=& \frac{n^2 - 1 + n + 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{n}}{n} - n \\=& n +1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}  - n \\=& 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}.\end{align*}


There's a little bit of sleight of hand starting with the assumption that $f(x) = a^x$ is well defined. But if you finesse how you know that, it's not hard to prove that
$$
f'(x) = cf(x)
$$
where $c$ is precisely the limit you ask about. Then $c = 1$ is the curve for which $a = e$ - that's the definition of $e$. It tells you $e^x$ is the function that's its own derivative. For the other exponential functions the constant is the derivative at $0$.
This is pretty natural. It's easy to see graphically that $e$ must be between $2$ and $3$: the function $3^x$ is too steep and $2^x$ is too shallow.
Your next job is to show why $a^x = e^{x\ln a}$ after defining $\ln$ as the inverse function of $e^x$.

We are now evaluating the following limit:
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} N \bigg[ {\Big( 1 + \frac {1}{M} \Big)}^{M / N} - 1 \bigg] = \, ?
$$
To begin with, we let $M \gg N$, $\left \lceil M / N \right \rceil = m$ and $\left \lfloor M / N \right \rfloor = n$. Then,
$$
{\Big( 1 + \frac {1}{M} \Big)}^{M / N} \ge {\Big( 1 + \frac {1}{M} \Big)}^{n} > 1 + \frac {n}{M},
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
{\Big( 1 + \frac {1}{M} \Big)}^{M / N}
& \le {\Big( 1 + \frac {1}{M} \Big)}^{m} \\
& = 1 + \frac {m}{M} + \frac {m \left( m - 1 \right)}{2 {M}^{2}} + \frac {m \left( m - 1 \right) \left( m - 2 \right)}{6 {M}^{3}} + \cdots \\
& < 1 + \frac {m}{M} + \frac {{m}^{2}}{2 {M}^{2}} + \frac {{m}^{3}}{4 {M}^{3}} + \cdots \\
& = 1 + \frac {m}{M} \cdot \frac {1}{1 - m / ( 2 M )}.
\end{align}
$$
Using the above results, we show
$$
\frac {n}{M / N} < N \bigg[ {\Big( 1 + \frac {1}{M} \Big)}^{M / N} - 1 \bigg] < \frac {m}{M / N} \cdot \frac {1}{1 - m / ( 2 M )},
$$
where $m, n \to \infty$ as $M \to \infty$, and $m / (2 M) \to 0$ as $N \to 0$. So, by the squeeze theorem,
$$
\boxed {\lim_{N \to \infty} \lim_{M \to \infty} N \bigg[ {\Big( 1 + \frac {1}{M} \Big)}^{M / N} - 1 \bigg] = 1.}
$$

You can assume that $h$ in both limits tends to 0 at the same rate because they are only parameters. I mean, write
$$a = \lim_{t \to 0}(1+t)^{1/t}. $$
Then,
$$\lim_{h \to 0}(\frac{a^h-1}h) = \lim_{h \to 0} \left[ \frac{\left(\lim_{t \to 0}(1+t)^{1/t}\right)^h - 1}{h}\right] = \lim_{h \to 0} \left[ \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\left(\left(1+t\right)^{1/t}\right)^h - 1}{h}\right].$$
Making the variable change $t = h$, we have that
$$ \lim_{h \to 0}(a^h-1) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \left[ \frac{\left(\left(1+h\right)^{1/h}\right)^h - 1}{h}\right] = \lim_{h \to 0} 1 = 1.$$
It is important to note that $\lim_{t \to 0 }\left(1+t\right)^{1/t}$ exists. So, for every $h$,  you can use the limits propriety that
$$\left(\lim_{t \to 0 }\left(1+t\right)^{1/t}\right)^h =\lim_{t \to 0}\left( \left(1+t\right)^{1/t}\right)^h. $$

No, it is not in general true that $\lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{t \to 0} f(t,h) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(h,h)$. For example, $$\lim_{h \to 0} \left[ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t}{t+h} \right] = 0$$ but $$\lim_{h \to 0} \left[ \frac{h}{h+h} \right] = \frac12.$$
